# Background of Selected Item in Picker

Tags: swiftui

I have a picker that looks like this:
[image: I have a picker that looks like this]

With the code being this:

```
 @State var typeSelection: String = "Socialism"
    var typeOptions = ["Socialism", "Democratic Socialism", "Capitalism", "Authoritarianism"]
```

...

```
  Picker("Please pick a Type", selection: $typeSelection) {
                   ForEach(typeOptions, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                    }
                }
```

How do I make the background color of the selected one darker, like if say it's opacity is 30% of a black color right now how do I bump that to 70%?

Comment: This is the default behavior of picker. So you can't change the selected item's background color yet (SwiftUI 2.0).

Comment: @egeeke: But also not possible in UIKit as well! I mean we could never change it. It was not possible from beginning.